# Changing UIScrollView frame in scrollViewDidScroll removes bouncing on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, bounce

Something strange happening, when I scroll in a UIScrollView I want to move it up and expand it's height because it's too small by default. It works fine and I listen to the scrollViewDidScroll delegate but that disables the bouncing on top!

Even if I do this in scrollViewDidScroll top bouncing is gone, bottom still bounces:

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.scrollView.frame, 0, 0);
```

This is my actual code in scrollViewDidScroll:

```
self.maxScrollDistance = 400;

if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= self.maxScrollDistance) {
    float newY = self.startScrollViewY - scrollView.contentOffset.y / 3;
    float newScrollViewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - newY;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, newY, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, newScrollViewHeight);
}
```

Anyone a hint to what might be the problem, a video of the problem in action:
[Bounce Problem Simulator recording](http://cl.ly/ZQHz)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is this the only relevant code? Do you set your content offset anywhere?

Comment: Oh, actually... You said you're expanding the height? Or are you shrinking it?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Yes expanding the height but also here, not setting content offset anywhere else,  this is the entire class: https://gist.github.com/thomasdegry/882ac33831b505952a8e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frame is always changing when scrolling to bottom, and it's not bouncing because changing frame when scrolling in negative contentOffset.y

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= self.maxScrollDistance)
```

Try to catch when scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 and set its changes frame.

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.maxScrollDistance && scrollView.contentOffset.y>0) {
    // Todo
}else if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -self.maxScrollDistance && scrollView.contentOffset.y<0){
    // Todo
}
```

// Try this code :

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.maxScrollDistance && scrollView.contentOffset.y>0) {
    float newY = self.startScrollViewY - scrollView.contentOffset.y / 3;
    float newScrollViewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - newY;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, newY, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, newScrollViewHeight);

}else if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -self.maxScrollDistance && scrollView.contentOffset.y<0){
    float newY = self.startScrollViewY + scrollView.contentOffset.y / 3;
    float newScrollViewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height + newY;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, newY, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, newScrollViewHeight);
}
```

Comment: How do you mean, like this? [gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasdegry/24a9ef825abfed752c53)